# grep curl output starting with string but show without it

Tags: bash, grep

```
   curl -i -v --silent \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '
   {some data>
   }' \
     https://foo  2>&1 |grep  -w '^boo:'    }
```

I receive

```
boo: foo
```

I only want the foo string without whitespace

Comment: using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for processing `json` is safer as grep.

Answer (score 1):

```
2>&1 | grep  -w '^boo:' | awk -F' ' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need grep + awk . awk can do the grep job without any problem.

for a file like this:

```
$ cat file1
too: soo
boo: foo
boofoo: wow
boof: nonono
koo: loo
```

This works fine:

```
$ awk '/^boo:/{print $2}' file1
foo
```

`awk` by default uses whitespace as fields delimiter, so you don't need `-F' '` also

In your case just pipe curl to awk: `curl ....|awk '/^boo:/{print $2}'`

PS: You can also use `gnu grep` if available like this: `grep -Po '^boo: \K.*' file1`